# how to normalise a list of list using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
f = [[7.0, 5.0, 9.0, 7.0], [7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 6.0], [12.0, 6.0, 5.0, 7.0], [5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0], [9.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0], [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0], [0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 21.0, 4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 14.0, 11.0, 1.0], [3.0, 4.0, 20.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0], [30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [4.0, 8.0, 5.0, 12.0], [7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 6.0], [5.0, 8.0, 8.0, 5.0], [6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 10.0], [9.0, 3.0, 7.0, 7.0]]
```

This is my list. I need to normalize this data. I've tried using this code

```
a=[(float(i) for i in d) for d in f)/(sum(j) for j in f)]
```

but I'm getting an error. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Change to `[[float(i)/sum(j) for i in j ]for j in f]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion might come from the fact that you're trying to mix two distinct, nested list comprehension syntaxes.

All the examples assume that you have a list of list of floats. If it's not the case, you can convert your nested list first :

```
f = [[float(i) for i in j] for j in f]
```

## Flat list with a double comprehension

The first one returns a flat list:

```
f = [[7.0, 5.0, 9.0, 7.0], [7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 6.0], [12.0, 6.0, 5.0, 7.0], [5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0], [9.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0], [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30.0], [0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 21.0, 4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 14.0, 11.0, 1.0], [3.0, 4.0, 20.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0], [30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [4.0, 8.0, 5.0, 12.0], [7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 6.0], [5.0, 8.0, 8.0, 5.0], [6.0, 8.0, 2.0, 10.0], [9.0, 3.0, 7.0, 7.0]]

a1 = [i / sum(j) for j in f for i in j]
print(a1)
# [0.25, 0.17857142857142858, 0.32142857142857145, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2857142857142857, 0.21428571428571427, 0.4, 0.2, 0.16666666666666666, 0.23333333333333334, 0.16666666666666666, 0.23333333333333334, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.16666666666666666, 0.2, 0.3333333333333333, 0.06666666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9333333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06666666666666667, 0.7, 0.13333333333333333, 0.1, 0.13333333333333333, 0.4666666666666667, 0.36666666666666664, 0.03333333333333333, 0.1, 0.13333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.13793103448275862, 0.27586206896551724, 0.1724137931034483, 0.41379310344827586, 0.25, 0.21428571428571427, 0.32142857142857145, 0.21428571428571427, 0.19230769230769232, 0.3076923076923077, 0.3076923076923077, 0.19230769230769232, 0.23076923076923078, 0.3076923076923077, 0.07692307692307693, 0.38461538461538464, 0.34615384615384615, 0.11538461538461539, 0.2692307692307692, 0.2692307692307692]
```

## Nested list with a double comprehension

The second one returns nested lists:

```
a2 = [[i / sum(j) for i in j] for j in f]
print(a2)
# [[0.25, 0.17857142857142858, 0.32142857142857145, 0.25], [0.25, 0.25, 0.2857142857142857, 0.21428571428571427], [0.4, 0.2, 0.16666666666666666, 0.23333333333333334], [0.16666666666666666, 0.23333333333333334, 0.3, 0.3], [0.3, 0.16666666666666666, 0.2, 0.3333333333333333], [0.06666666666666667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9333333333333333], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.06666666666666667, 0.7, 0.13333333333333333, 0.1], [0.13333333333333333, 0.4666666666666667, 0.36666666666666664, 0.03333333333333333], [0.1, 0.13333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 0.1], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.13793103448275862, 0.27586206896551724, 0.1724137931034483, 0.41379310344827586], [0.25, 0.21428571428571427, 0.32142857142857145, 0.21428571428571427], [0.19230769230769232, 0.3076923076923077, 0.3076923076923077, 0.19230769230769232], [0.23076923076923078, 0.3076923076923077, 0.07692307692307693, 0.38461538461538464], [0.34615384615384615, 0.11538461538461539, 0.2692307692307692, 0.2692307692307692]]
```

Note the difference in the order of `for i` and `for j`.

Also, both syntaxes calculate sum(j) for each iteration.

## Normalize function

To avoid this, you could define a `normalize` function:

```
def normalize(l):
    s = sum(l)
    return [i/s for i in l]

print([normalize(j) for j in f])
```

## Map and zip

Finally, you could use a combination of `map` and `zip`:

```
sums = map(sum, f)
print([[i/s for i in j] for j,s in zip(f, sums)])
```

Comment: ive tried ur code but im getting error-TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @prilinsh: It means you have a mix of object types in your lists. In your example list, you have a list of list of floats. No integer or string.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from __future__ import division #to avoid integer division
normalized_list = [[a/sum(el) for a in el] for el in f]
```

Comment: Why is division needed? There's no integer anywhere.

Comment: slight nitpick: `sum(el)` is computed at each iteration.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Avoiding that would require a loop which is also ok. I do not think you can do this with a list comprehension

Comment: @EricDuminil, in case there appear lists consisting of integers, so the code is more universal

Comment: You can use a list comp if you compute the sums in advance and store them in a map. Basically any method would involve some prelim setup.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes. You can't. So maybe listcomp isn't the best way to do that. That would require some benching.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[float(i)/sum(d) for i in d] for d in f]
```

This equivalent of :

```
res = []
for d in f :
    res1 =[]
    for i in d: 
        res1.append(float(i)/sum(d))
    res.append(res1)
```

Comment: in what this answer is different from the previous ones?

Comment: @EricDuminil Why is not equivalent ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in that.

I would first try to loop through the list to see if it works as expected.

```
for i in f:
  print [float(j)/sum(i) for j in i]
```

You can also do:

```
a = [(float(j)/sum(i) for j in i) for i in f]
```

Comment: in what this answer is different from the previous ones?